# deleting inactive picklist values

Tags: picklist

I want to delete inactive picklist values and while deleting I want to replace them with the new value. Does it cause any data inconsistency ? For ex I have inactive (NEWJERSEY) value that is also in use in some records and I have an active (NewJersey) value. I have replace option while deleting the inactive value and I want to change the value with the active one while deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

It won't cause any problems. When you delete the inactive value and choose a replacement, that new value will be applied to all records.